# CodeIgniter White Screen after migrating from DSO to FCGI

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I've encountered a problem where codeigniter returns a whitescreen to me.

Note: this was working fine when I was still in DSO.
Note: I have tried changing the value of $config['uri_protocol']

Consider this example:

```
url> mysite.com/process/something/321
output> **** WHITESCREEN ****

url> mysite.com/process/something/321/2323
output> you have entered: 321

url> mysite.com/process/something/323/2asdfshdf
output> you have entered: 323

url> mysite.com/process/something/323
output> **** WHITESCREEN ****
```

code:

```
class process extends Controller{
  public function something($digit){
    die("you have entered: " . $digit);
  }
}
```

what do I need to do to get rid of the whitescreen?

Comment: which version of CI are you using and do you have errors on? For most part whitescreen shows up when there is an php error, and errors are off.

Comment: http://www.serveridol.com/2012/02/15/codeigniter-%E2%80%93-no-input-file-specified-error/  Wonder if that will help?

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter 1.7.2.

This started occurring when I migrated from DSO to FCGI.

Comment: @RickCalder, alright I'm gonna give that solution a shot. will advise.

Comment: @RickCalder, it worked! many thanks! :) posting your comment as solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as commented by @Rick Calder, there's a quick fix to this problem, you just have to update your .htaccess file. Thanks Rick!

solution can be found here: http://www.serveridol.com/2012/02/15/codeigniter-%E2%80%93-no-input-file-specified-error/

although I'm still curious as to why this happens and why it automatically converts decimal points to underscore.

ie.

```
url> mysite.com/process/something/111.222
output> you have entered: 111_222
```

i need to read more into this to verify why its happening.